# Windows Form more than 700 pages Print Issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some custom Windows Form, Loading each form dynamically and printing the forms control value using `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument`.

My Problem is, I have more than 700 pages to print, If print exceeds 300 pages I am getting out of memory issue, How to print more than 700 pages using `System.Drawing.Printing`

Comment: Who will read 700 pages? Unless you are printing a novel the problem could be a design issue since printing that much pages will kill the planet :S. The pages are possibly processed in memory, so the answer would be add more memory.

Comment: Yes. I understand, it will take more memory for 700 pages, but we have requirement to print morethan 700 pages continuously, each form have lot of controls, do we have any other option to print

Comment: It is possible that your code to do the printing is not disposing of some resource where it should.

Comment: You have to show us your printing code.  Most likely, you aren't disposing of resources.

Comment: We have the same problem currently. We are currently looking into splitting the print job in batches of 100 pages. This will mean that you will need to be able to determine the pages idividually.

Comment: Definitely a missing *using* or Dispose problem.  A PrintPage event handler will create a lot of System.Drawing objects but won't allocate enough memory to trigger a GC.  Diagnose it with Task Manager, add "GDI Objects" to see the number of undisposed objects.

Answer (score 0):

**PrintDocument** has **OnBeginPrint**(), you can override it in your inherited class (or handle as event subscribing to it). It passes argument which can tell you is this printing for preview or its actual printing (actually there are 3 values: **PrintToFile**, **PrintToPreview** and **PrintToPrinter**). You can distinguish the purpose of printing this way. Also, the only thing you need to know is that when you *Preview* your document, your **OnPrintPage**() will be called 700 times in a row building whole document in memory; when you actually *Print* document to the printer, after calling **OnPrintPage**() it will not keep in memory all the previous pages. That is why to print any document you actually need memory to store its most memory-heavy page only.

So all you need is to draw simplified pages content when previewing them and draw the page completely only while actual printing.

Next sample illustrates my approach:

```
class PrintDocument1 : PrintDocument
{
    int currentPage;
    bool isPreview;

    protected override void OnBeginPrint(PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        currentPage = 0;
        isPreview = e.PrintAction == PrintAction.PrintToPreview;
    }

    protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        currentPage++;

        if (isPreview)
        {
            // simplified page drawing

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.BurlyWood, e.MarginBounds);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Page #" + currentPage, SystemFonts.CaptionFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Location);
        }
        else
        {
            // full page drawing

            Bitmap[] bmaps = new Bitmap[] {
                SystemIcons.Application.ToBitmap(),
                SystemIcons.Information.ToBitmap(),
                SystemIcons.Question.ToBitmap(),
                SystemIcons.Warning.ToBitmap(),
                SystemIcons.Shield.ToBitmap(),
                SystemIcons.Error.ToBitmap()
            };

            Point p = e.MarginBounds.Location;
            for (int i = 0; p.Y < e.MarginBounds.Bottom; i++, p.Y += 40)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Some text goes here, line " + (i + 1), SystemFonts.CaptionFont, Brushes.Black, p);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.CadetBlue, e.MarginBounds.Left, p.Y, e.MarginBounds.Right, p.Y);
                for (int j = 0; j < bmaps.Length; j++)
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmaps[j], p.X + 200 + j * 40, p.Y);
            }
        }

        e.HasMorePages = currentPage < 700; // a lot of pages to draw
    }
}

// above class can be previewed and printed next way:
// PrintPreviewDialog d = new PrintPreviewDialog();
// d.Document = new PrintDocument1();
// d.ShowDialog();
```